# How to check if a page is allowed to be iframed?

Tags: javascript, iframe

What I want to do is to iframe some pages dynamically, so when user clicks a certain button a certain page(link generated with the button dynamically)opens in an iframe. I want to skip urls those don't allow their contents to be iframed.

Is there any way to check if a URL restricts itself to be iframed?

Comment: In the browser, you're probably limited, but on the serverside you can check the `X-Frame-Options` header, as that's what everyone uses now anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Make an `AJAX` request for the URL, check for an `x-frame-options` header. If it is `DENY` or `SAMEORIGIN` then you probably can't show it.

```
var xhr = $.get("http://somewhere.com");
xhr.always(function () {
  var frameOption = xhr.getResponseHeader("x-frame-options");
  if (frameOption == "DENY") {
    // etc.
  }
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

As adeneo points out, this may fail for a lot of sites with cross domain policies. You best bet is going to be to check the URL on your own back end.

Add a route to your server that takes a URL, fetches it and checks if it can be framed.

Comment: I'm guessing that doesn't work at all on cross-domain sites ?

Comment: If I'm not wrong ajax won't work for cross-domain sites?

Answer (score 0):

There is now reliable way to say for sure that the URL is not iframeable.

Most of those URLs can be excluded with an Ajax request and checking the `X-Frame-Options` header in the response. (Disregarding the "Same origin policy")

Other sites use a script to check if they are iframed, those sites can only be excluded by "testing" the site in a hidden iframe and check the content yourself, of course this is only applicable if you know the expected content, or at least some key elements.
To prevent the loaded iframe from redirecting your own page, you can use the [IFrame-Sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) or alternativly checking `onbeforeunload`

Comment: Ajax really isn't an option, as checking if the page can be framed is sure to be cross domain, and anyone that doesn't allow framing surely won't allow cross domain calls. A hidden iframe isn't an option either, for X-Frame headers, no special events are fired, and the response would still be 200, and most frame busting techniques redirect the parent window, so the hidden iframe would just redirect your page.

Comment: I agree, Ajax is in most cases no option, but there are scenarios where it is, e.g. iframeing a legacy application on the same domain. The hidden iframe option is possible, not beautiful, but possible, checking onbeforeunload in parent frame and onload in iframe.

Comment: Also with HTML5 the "sandbox" attribute can be used.

Answer (score -3):

I don't believe there is any restrictions between a page and an iframe. I do know that the page can check via javascript if its inside an iframe.

Comment: [***We Done Been ... Framed!***](http://blog.codinghorror.com/we-done-been-framed/)

Comment: Aside from cross browser scripting there is no restrictions. Meaning you can load any page into a iframe from any site. It would be up to the site to TRY and bust out of an iframe, if of course it can.

Comment: You're not really answering the question at all. The OP is asking how to detect if a site can't be loaded, for instance if there is an `X-Frame` header, or frame busting, it's not really clear, so answering *"There are no restrictions"*  isn't even close to an answer ?